# Get the number of days since file is last modified

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I want to get the number of days since file last modified date to today's date.

I use this `$ ls -l uname.txt | awk '{print  $6 , "", $7}'`  but it gives me the last modified date.  I want to know the number of days from a last modified date to today's date.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using `ls`, you can use `date -r` to tell you the modification date of the file. In addition to that, `date`'s `%s` specifier, which formats the date in seconds since the epoch, is useful for calculations. Combining the two easily results in the desired number of days:

```
mod=$(date -r uname.txt +%s)
now=$(date +%s)          
days=$(expr \( $now - $mod \) / 86400)
echo $days
```

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ftime=`stat -c %Y uname.txt`
ctime=`date +%s`
diff=$(( (ctime - ftime) / 86400 ))
echo $diff
```

Comment: @Stunner `86400 = 24*60*60` (i.e. number of seconds in a day)

Comment: Somehow the above script is giving me the same answer i.e  15981 for all the files even though the last modified date is different.

Comment: @Stunner How are you invoking the script? Are you aware that it unconditionally examines `uname.txt`?

Comment: @Stunner if you want to pass a file into the script, replace `uname.txt` with `$1`

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap up the differences of GNU and BSD stat with some BASH math and basic readable API:

```
since_last_modified() {
   local modified
   local now=$(date +%s)
   local period=$2

   stat -f %m $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 && modified=$(stat -f %m $1) # BSD stat
   stat -c %Y $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 && modified=$(stat -c %Y $1) # GNU stat

   case $period in
        day|days)    period=86400 ;; # 1 day in seconds
       hour|hours)   period=1440  ;; # 1 hour in seconds
     minute|minutes) period=60    ;; # 1 minute in seconds
           *)        period=      ;; # default to seconds
   esac

   if [[ $period > 0 ]]; then
      echo "$(( (now - modified) / period ))"
   else
      echo "$(( now - modified ))"
   fi
}
```

Basic usage of seconds since last modification:

```
since_last_modified uname.txt
```

or minutes saved to a variable

```
minutes_since=$(since_last_modified uname.txt minutes)
```